# Formatting dates

Tags: perl

April 9, 2012 can be written in any of these ways:

```
4912
4/9/12
4-9-12
4 9 12
04-9-12
04-09-12
4 9 2012
4 09 2012
(I think you get the point)
```

For those of you that don't understand, the rules are:

```
1. Dates may or may not have ` `, `-` or `/` between them
2. The year can be written as 2 digits (assumed to be dates in the range of [2000, 2099] inclusive) or 4 digits
3. One digit month/days may or may not have leading zeroes.
```

How would you go about problem solving this to format the dates into 04/09/12?

I know the dates can be ambiguous, i.e., 12112 can be 12/1/12 or 1/21/12, but assume the smallest month possible.

Comment: I presume your question is about how to parse dates that could be in any of the formats you've given?

Comment: No, don't do this without modules.

Comment: Well, not just parsing but parse it and format it to the requested format.

Comment: Would "11113" be 11-1-2013 or 1-11-2013?

Comment: What date is `12212`?

Comment: @SinanÜnür: no, not a dup (though by the same user), since this one actually explains what the output should be

Comment: @gpojd: the previous copy of this question said "Indeed, I guess in those cases I will just assume the date is 1-12-13. I don't need 100% accuracy, I just need to get most of the cases down."

Comment: Yes, this is not the same question because this asks for output. Assume 11113 to be 1-11-13 or 1-11-13, of your choosing.

Comment: previous question also stipulated a regex; this doesn't

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to figure out how I would approach formatting the dates. I was thinking, if I had a date such as `4912`, I would get the first two digits `(49)`. If this value is greater than 12 or if it's a digit followed by a non-digit (`4-9-12`), then I would add a `0` into the front of `49` creating `049`. Then, I would substring to get `04`. I would repeat a similar process for the date and year, but this wouldn't work out because I don't know where the date begins. It could either be at position 1, 2, or 3. Also, this solution seems really bad. I'm sure there's a better solution.

Comment: Why try to do this without modules? Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, this is a problem I'm dealing with in my homework.

Comment: If I gave such a homework problem, I would expect an answer that gave an error on ambiguous input :)

Comment: some days I feel like just marking every question as a duplicate of some other randomly chosen question until there is a provision for voting *against* closing.

Comment: Then you have several questions to consider. `11111111` is unambiguous, and so 8s `111`, but what do you want to do with string of between `'1' x 4` and `'1' x 7`?

Comment: Just assume whichever date you'd like. As long as they follow all the rules, then it's good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually is something that regexes are good at; making an assumption, moving forward with it, then backtracking if necessary to get a successful match.

```
s{
    \A 
    ( 1[0-2] | 0?[1-9] )
    [-/ ]?
    ( 3[01] | [12][0-9] | 0?[1-9] )
    [-/ ]?
    ( (?: [0-9]{2} ){1,2} )
    \z
 }
 {
    sprintf '%02u/%02u/%04u', $1, $2, ( length $3 == 4 ? $3 : 2000+$3 )
 }xe;
```

The range checks present, while not determined by the value of the month, should be sufficient to pick a good date from the ambiguous cases (where there is a good date).

Note that it is important to try two digit month and days first; otherwise 111111 becomes 1-1-1111, not the presumably intended 11-11-11.  But this means 11111 will prefer to be 11-1-11, not 1-11-11.

If a valid day of month check is needed, it should be performed after reformatting.

Notes:

`s{}{}` is a substitution using curly braces instead of / to delimit the parts of the regex to avoid having to escape the /, and also because using paired delimiters allows opening and closing both the pattern and replacement parts, which looks nice to me.

`\A` matches the start of the string being matched; `\z` matches the end.  `^` and `$` are often used for this, but can have slightly different meanings in some cases; I prefer these since they always only mean one thing.

The x flag on the end says this is an extended regex that can have extra whitespace or comments that are ignored, so that it is more readable.  (Whitespace inside a character class isn't ignored.)  The e flag says the replacement part isn't a string, it is code to execute.

`'%02u/%02u/%02u'` is a printf format, used for taking values and formatting them in a particular way; see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html.

Comment: I'm still quite new to Perl, so could you please comment on what your code does? I don't know what the `s bracket` is doing or the `\A` or `\z` or the `xe` or the `%02u/%02u/%02u`.

Comment: Added explanation; any other questions?

Comment: Great solution! However, I'm guessing I have to check if the year is, for example, `04` and append `20` in the beginning then reconcatenate it with the string?

Comment: You originally said "format the dates into 04/09/12", but ok...

Answer (score 1):

Install Date::Calc

On ubuntu libdate-calc-perl

This should be able to read in all those dates ( except 4912, 4 9 2012, 4 09 2012 ) and then output them in a common format